# What does "throw one's hat in the ring for" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read the following sentence:

> Wikipedia has a great list of ORMs that exist for just about any language. That list is missing JavaScript, which is my language of choice, so I will **throw my hat in the ring** for Knex.js.

What does "throw my hat in the ring for" mean?

Comment: Can you provide us with the source? Where is this from?

Comment: You can easily google this expression, Niing. https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/throw-your-hat-in-the-ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone stated, that you easily can Google it, but I've just found a few links for you.

My answer is taken directly from [this](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/throw-your-hat-into-the-ring.html) website.

The definition is to make or take up a challenge, or demonstrate one's willingness to join an enterprise.

Here are some other links to find the meaning:

[What does 'Throw your hat in the ring' mean](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw-your-hat-into-the-ring)

[Throw your hat in the ring - Meaning](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/throw+your+hat+in+the+ring.html)

[Throw your hat into the ring](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ThrowYourHatInTheRing/chkqz/post.htm)

Hope it helps!